# how to remove blue border around links in IE9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm working on this site: http://amberdreams.com

This is a pretty simple site, and I've been using netrenderer.com to make sure that all the pages work in Internet Explorer.

Despite my best efforts, I have not been able to remove the blue border around the facebook and twitter links on the home page for this site when viewing it with Internet Explorer 9.

```
img {border: none; }
a img {border: 0px; }
```

I've tried variations of the code above, and it successfully removes the blue border for every version of IE except 9. Any ideas?

Comment: there is no border in IE9/8/7

Comment: it might also be a plugin, like for example, Skype would detect phone numbers in the page and convert them to links

Answer (score 26):

Try this in your CSS, worked for me.

```
img {text-decoration: none; border: 0px}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that should be fine.

You might want to clear your cache and try again...

If not maybe try:

```
a{border:none}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following instead in your css:

```
border-style:none;
```

That should remove your border issue.

Answer (score 1):

Visibility of the border around links depends on user settings in IE. Set `A {text-decoration: none; border: 0px}`.

It seems, that your video-object is not loaded in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [great post on removing outline](http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/) with separate remark about IE9:

> George Langley wrote in to say that IE 9 apparently doesn't allow you to remove the dotted outline around links unless you include this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Answer (score 1):

//Add to your CSS

```
* {-ms-box-sizing:border-box;}
img {outline-style: none;}
```

//Add to your HTML

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case the working code (generated by mailchimp and added a rule for 'a') was:

```
img,a img,a{
    border:0;
    height:auto;
    outline:none;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

so it is an assumption of other answers

Answer (score -2):

The best way is to add a CSS attribute

```
a:link, a:visited { text-decoration: none}
```

If you want to change colors when you hover the mouse, add

```
a:hover {color: x } // x = the color of your choice
```