# How can I remove the dotted border from <area> elements in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

In Firefox (current version 14.0.1) I get a dotted outline around some `<area>` tags that I have created [here (http://mediabrands.com.au/)](http://mediabrands.com.au/). Not only do I see a dotted line, but once it has appeared I can't get rid of it (by clicking another area for example).

[image]

I've searched around here and Google for a considerable amount of time, and still haven't managed to get rid of them. They do not appear in any other browsers.

Things I have tried (and all combinations of the below) without success:

- Add `outline: none` to the img, map and area tags (and their `:focus` and `:active`) counterparts.
- Added `border: none` to each of those.
- Added `hidefocus="hidefocus"` to each of those.
- Added various combinations using `::-moz-focus-inner{ border: none; outline: none; }` to each of those elements.
- Added `.focus(function(){ $(this).blur(); })` (jQuery) to each of those.

I believe I've exhausted all the information I've been able to come across - is there any other way to get rid of these lines?

Here is the HTML for quick reference, and for the possibility of something in there being the reason I can't get rid of it:

```
<img src="anatomy/dial/components/foundation.png" id="dial-map" usemap="#dial" />
<map name="dial">
    <area title="Ansible" class="tab" id="click-ansible" shape="poly" coords="412,419,376,447,313,474,248,487,247,434,327,415,374,377" href="#">
    <area title="Cadreon" class="tab" id="click-cadreon" shape="poly" coords="487,245,478,313,455,366,416,417,378,380,429,299,434,246" href="#">
    <area title="Orion" class="tab" id="click-orion" shape="poly" coords="418,73,453,117,482,191,484,242,431,244,422,180,378,111" href="#">
    <area title="Ensemble" class="tab" id="click-ensemble" shape="poly" coords="247,1,311,10,368,35,415,70,378,108,312,66,244,53" href="#">
    <area title="Reprise" class="tab" id="click-reprise" shape="poly" coords="73,69,111,39,176,8,242,2,243,53,172,66,112,108" href="#">
    <area title="Magna Global" class="tab" id="click-magnaglobal" shape="poly" coords="245,487,186,481,114,450,71,417,110,377,175,423,246,432" href="#">
    <area title="Airborne" class="tab" id="click-airborne" shape="poly" coords="69,414,37,373,12,316,2,244,55,244,68,322,106,375" href="#">
    <area title="Marketing Sciences" class="tab" id="click-analytics" shape="poly" coords="2,242,11,171,33,120,71,74,109,109,70,168,54,241" href="#">
    <area title="MB3" class="tab" id="click-mb3" shape="poly" coords="257,430,178,422,120,384,82,340,140,305,163,337,206,360,262,364,317,342,348,305,404,340,384,367,324,413" href="#">
    <area title="UM" class="tab" id="click-um" shape="poly" coords="307,134,245,116,246,56,309,68,375,109,418,178,430,237,429,288,404,339,350,303,368,246,358,198,344,169" href="#">
    <area title="Initiative" class="tab" id="click-initiative" shape="poly" coords="80,339,63,289,58,235,72,171,109,112,176,67,243,56,242,119,192,128,152,159,126,206,122,261,137,306" href="#">
    <area title="View Website" id="website" shape="poly" coords="173,330,139,292,133,213,161,167,196,143,245,129,305,146,336,176,359,246,339,300,309,335,260,352,209,351" href="#">
</map>
```

Comment: @Asad Yep, tried that over `none` too.

Comment: i feel really bad for saying this but try it again with !important? or in some sort of isolated environment without all the extra css and js around.

Comment: @Asad Sorry yeah I've tried everything using `!important` too.

Comment: there are a bunch of questions asking pretty much the same thing on SO that have fizzled out without accepted answers. I'm going to put a bounty on this tomorrow.

Comment: @MartyWallace Have you tried the `:selection` pseudo selector?

Comment: @MattWhipple Gave it a shot, no luck either.

Comment: Try  using firebug to see which styles are applied?

Comment: @Ben Yeah, checked Firebug and didn't see anything unusual like browser forced outline styles etc.

Comment: @A.M.K This is a website for a global company (IPG Mediabrands) for which I work under a digital branch. The majority of the managers in the building are on versions of Firefox much lower than 14 and it's not in my power to have 500+ staff upgrade their browsers. Moreover, updating to the latest browser should never be the solution.

Comment: @A.M.K Yeah unfortunately there's a paradigm in place across the office network that doesn't allow employees to upgrade their software on their own but rather they need to go through IT (and it needs to be a company-wide update instead of individuals).

Comment: @MartyWallace Got it, please see my solution and demo below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is your blur-focus function on line 151 of dial.js. Removing it fixes the issue.

```
$("img, area, map").focus(function(event) {
    $(this).blur();
});
```

To prevent focusing on area elements, set a [`tabindex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19000539/900747)to `-1`, i.e.

```
<area tabindex="-1" title="Ansible" class="tab" id="click-ansible" shape="poly" coords="...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/K8Adx/

Comment: I had `<area  onfocus="blur();"`, so I deleted !, but I added that code for some bug, that I don't remember now, I think its a bug for Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that blurring on focus is causing the problem:

Remove from dial.js:

```
// Prevent focus of areas.
$("img, area, map").focus(function() {
    $(this).blur();
});
```

Here is a fiddle I made to simplify everything: http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/gDrAS/
Comment and uncomment the javascript to see the different results.

---

A solution for the blur and focus is to use `event.preventDefault()`. So you can replace the what is removed above to:

```
// Prevent focus of areas.
$("img, area, map").focus(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

There is also a `tabindex` fix using `tabindex="-1"` attribute.

Comment: I believe the information about `stopPropagation` is wrong. From the docs _Note that this will not prevent other handlers on the same element from running._  It may have seemed to work because its misspelled in your code sample and may have caused a break. `event.preventDefault` would be more appropriate (or a combination) but in quick testing only `return false;` seemed to work consistently.

Comment: @MattWhipple Thanks for the spelling check. Fixed it. I am sure that there are a few more functions that will produce the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting the area Focus and active states to border 0 as the following:

as per the following question: [Blue border around image maps in Internet Explorer 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193613/blue-border-around-image-maps-in-internet-explorer-9)

```
a,
img {
  outline: none;
}
map > area,
map > area:active,
map > area:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a solution for Internet Explorer. The question is about Firefox.

Comment: Thats correct but the css may still fix the problem in FF. according to the question he hasnt tried the :focus and :active. I'd give it a go as the dotted lines only seem to occur after you click the link.

Comment: @Aaron Check out *point 1* in my question under "Things I have tried...".

Answer (score -2):

Try using CSS: `text-decoration:none;`